# Iionic Chat Client with Dialogflow v.2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, dialogflow-es, ionic4

I have been trying to find an existing Ionic 3 Chat client to integrate with Dialogflow v.2. All the clients I can find and examples are with Dialogflow v.1 and the Cordova plugin only supports V.1. Does anyone have experience with this are have created a client with the Dialogflow V.2 API? All help much appreciated Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use the [Dialogflow libraries](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-dialogflow) to develop and integrate it with the ionic chat.

The other way is to use the third-party applications which support DialogflowV2 and integrate. Here's the [article](https://www.kommunicate.io/blog/building-ionic-cordova-chatbot-dialogflow-api-ai/) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the official Cordova and Javascript clients will stop working in October 23th, 2019. 
No news yet of an update to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [nodejs-dialogflow](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-dialogflow) library. [Here](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-dialogflow#using-the-client-library) is an example you can use to get you started.

Also, check the [Dialogflow quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/quickstart-api#top_of_page) for setting up the authentication.

Comment: When running the node library in an Ionic application it gives a ton of errors and won't compile.

Can't resolve 'tls'
Can't resolve 'net'
Can't resolve 'child_process'
Can't resolve 'fs'
(And more similar to that) These look to be modules built-into node?

Comment: I've already encountered a similar issue. Are you using webpack? Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57419528/7517757)

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't using webpack. I think we just ended up just using @angular/common/http and posting JSON direct to Dialogflow. Will look at this if we go down a different path.