# How to port data from BigQuery into a ReactJS webpack app already deployed on Google App Engine

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-bigquery, kepler.gl

I have successfully managed to deploy an app based on kepler.gl on Google App Engine with some sample data (based on the [vis academy](https://vis.academy/#/kepler.gl/setup) tutorial). What I would like is to be able to get data from Big Query and pass that as the source data.

I've tried to implement the example in [nodejs-bigquery sample](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigquery/blob/master/samples/query.js), but cannot figure out how to pass the results into the main app.js file. I'm an absolute beginner in app development and javascript so any help would be highly appreciated.

Here's how my main app.js file looks like

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import AutoSizer from 'react-virtualized/dist/commonjs/AutoSizer';
import KeplerGl from 'kepler.gl';

// Kepler.gl actions
import {addDataToMap} from 'kepler.gl/actions';
// Kepler.gl Data processing APIs
import Processors from 'kepler.gl/processors';

// Sample data
//import data from './data/bq.js'

....
```

Here's the error output:

```
ERROR in ./~/https-proxy-agent/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in '/Users/saroosh/code/GAE/node_modules/https-proxy-agent'
 @ ./~/https-proxy-agent/index.js 5:10-24
 @ ./~/teeny-request/build/src/index.js
 @ ./~/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js
 @ ./~/@google-cloud/common/build/src/index.js
 @ ./~/@google-cloud/bigquery/build/src/index.js
 @ ./src/data/bq.js
 @ ./src/app.js
 @ ./src/main.js

ERROR in ./~/https-proxy-agent/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in '/Users/saroosh/code/GAE/node_modules/https-proxy-agent'
 @ ./~/https-proxy-agent/index.js 6:10-24
 @ ./~/teeny-request/build/src/index.js
 @ ./~/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js
 @ ./~/@google-cloud/common/build/src/index.js
 @ ./~/@google-cloud/bigquery/build/src/index.js
 @ ./src/data/bq.js
 @ ./src/app.js
 @ ./src/main.js
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an issue with webpack. I found some issues related with webpack integrations. I got some workarounds from [here](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues/1563) and you can find more information [here](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/447).

As for the workarounds, if you are using the webpack.config.js provided in the [vis academy tutorial](https://vis.academy/#/kepler.gl/setup), try this:

Replace this part in webpack.config.js:

```
node: {
    fs: 'empty'
  },
```

With this:

```
node: {
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty',
  },
```

Solution provided by @tanohzana